# How to concatenate rows based on group as quickly as possible

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, data.table, concatenation

I have a dataframe as follows

```
ClientVisitGUID LineNum TextCol
1                 1      This was a great
1                 2      report I did
2                 3      was performed today
2                 1      Another great report
2                 2      for this person
3                 2      good stuff
3                 1      I really write very
3                 3      when I put my
3                 4      mind to it
```

I'd like to concatenate the rows based on the `ClientVisitGUID` and the line number so i can get the following output

```
ClientVisitGUID TextCol
1               This was a great report I did
2               Another great report for this person was performed today
3               I really write very good stuff when I put my mind to it
```

I tried `dplyr` but it takes a long time and can't deal with thousands of rows which is what I have

```
  resultset2<-resultset %>%
    group_by(ClientVisitGUID) %>%
    arrange(LineNum) %>%
    summarize_all(paste, collapse=",")
```

Is there a faster way? I'm not really familiar with data.table but is this fast?

Comment: I'm not a data.table user. I know it's super fast but it's not as friendly as dplyr. Have you tried parellilizing your work? (https://blog.aicry.com/multidplyr-dplyr-meets-parallel-processing/index.html). You could also manually split your tibble into chunks and apply your group-by to each chunk and then combine.

Comment: @lmeninato I did think of that but wanted to see if a simple alternative to dplyr would suffice. I think Ill have to parellelize eventually though. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A second `data.table` option, also using `stringi` for its performance

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
setDT(df)
setkey(df, ClientVisitGUID, LineNum)
df1 <- df[, .(new = stri_c(TextCol, collapse = " ")), by = ClientVisitGUID]
```

Result

```
df1
#   ClientVisitGUID                                                      new
#1:               1                            This was a great report I did
#2:               2 Another great report for this person was performed today
#3:               3  I really write very good stuff when I put my mind to it
```

**data** (thanks to @ThomasIsCoding)

```
df <- structure(list(ClientVisitGUID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), LineNum = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), TextCol = c("This was a great", 
"report I did", "was performed today", "Another great report", 
"for this person", "good stuff", "I really write very", "when I put my", 
"mind to it")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: if I have more columns how can I concatenate them at the same time. For example I also have another column with some text in called Textcol2 . How do I extend your solution to concatenate the text in this column too?

Comment: In the end for my bigger dataset (not shown here) I re-merged the columns from this solution back in to selected unique rows from the original datset which worked

Comment: @SebastianZeki Can you update your post with an example that shows `Textcol2` and desired output?

Answer (score 1):

An base R option is using `aggregate`

```
result <- aggregate(TextCol~ClientVisitGUID,
                    df[order(df$ClientVisitGUID,df$LineNum),],
                    paste0, 
                    collapse = " ")
```

which gives

```
> result
  ClientVisitGUID                                                  TextCol
1               1                            This was a great report I did
2               2 Another great report for this person was performed today
3               3  I really write very good stuff when I put my mind to it
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ClientVisitGUID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), LineNum = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), TextCol = c("This was a great", 
"report I did", "was performed today", "Another great report", 
"for this person", "good stuff", "I really write very", "when I put my", 
"mind to it")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding it seems pretty fast. If I want to aggregate more than the TextCol by ClientVisitID - what if I wanted the LineNum aggregated too?

Comment: @SebastianZeki Yes, you can use something like `cbind(TextCol,col1,col2,col3)~ClientVisitGUID` in `aggregate`, where `col1`,`col2`,`col3` are the column names you want to perform the similar operation over `TextCol`

Answer (score 0):

If you want speed, `data.table` is indeed a great candidate:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(resultset)
data.table::setkeyv(resultset, "ClientVisitGUID")
resultset <- resultset[order(ClientVisitGUID, LineNum)]
resultset[, .(lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ",")), by = "ClientVisitGUID"]
```

Setting the key takes some times at first but you will end up with faster operations afterwards. Setting the keys reorder rows belonging to the same group in contiguous memory slots

## Example

```r
data = data.table("a" = c("aaa","ffff","ttt"), "b" = c(1,1,2))
data[, .(lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ",")), by = "b"]
```

Comment: Maybe the `resultset[order(ClientVisitGUID, LineNum)]` line is unecessary if your data are already ordered. Since I have not seen your data, I included it in case

Comment: I get the error Error in .(lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ",")) : 
  could not find function "." I've tried to update data.table  (1.12.8) but still get it

Comment: Is `resultset` a `data.table` object ? (`inherits(resultset, "data.table")` is `TRUE` ?) I just tested a silly example on my computer and it works (added to the answer)

Comment: It's a data.table and a data.frame. Is that possible? Cant seem to get it to be a data.frame only. Would that the be the source of the error I have?

Comment: Everything looks normal then. Having also the `data.frame` class is not a problem, it's normal. `.` is supposed to be a shortcut for list. If you try, `resultset[, list(lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ",")), by = "ClientVisitGUID"]` or `resultset[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ","), by = "ClientVisitGUID"]`, do you still have the error ? (your version of `data.table` is more recent than mine)

Comment: I get Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list' with those two

Comment: What happens if you add `.SDcols` argument in your example like that:  `resultset[, .(lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ",")), by = "ClientVisitGUID", .SDcols = "TextCol"]` ?  Maybe before doing that, run `resultset[,TextCol:= as.character(TextCol)]` ? (`.SDcols` control which column is concerned by `lapply`)

Comment: I get the error Error in `:=`(alertTXT, as.character(alertTXT)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE so it seems that maybe it thinks I still have a dataframe (although str() says I have both

Comment: It's possible that you have a problem if your variable has been, in some ways, modified by `dplyr` before (I never had this problem so it's an assumption from [that](https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr/issues/51)). Sorry, that this solution does not work in your case